# Align One Large DIV with Two Smaller Ones

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image: desired result image]

This is my code:

```
!-- BIG ONE LEFT -->
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
              <a href="#"><img style="height: 420px;" class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Smalls -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
```

and this the result:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJRGYe

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: how to make looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7J0Y.png

Comment: does it have to strictly be all bootstrapped? I could give you a solution using `flex`

Comment: Any solution is accepted: D

Comment: @MichaelEvans he is already using flex as it's bootstrap V4

Comment: imply remove this `style="height: 420px;"` and you have what you want

Comment: not really, it is this space https://i.imgur.com/OqHCWyv.png 

the result I would like it to be: https://imgur.com/a/As4DK4I

Comment: come on :) it's a space that you can control by adding margin-top to the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use responsive spacing utils for padding-top..

```
<!-- BIG ONE LEFT -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Smalls -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 pt-lg-3 pt-0">
                <div class="card">
                    <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/wJvmJUlIu0

Comment: Thank you, I will do it that way.
I think it's the right one

Answer (score -1):

You could try this approach, using flexbox

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-left">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-right">
        <div class="flex-right-top">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-right-bottom">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-left {
  flex-basis: 66%;
}

.flex-right {
  flex-basis: 34%;
  display: flex; // for its child elements
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-right-top, .flex-right-bottom {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: no work for me  , the result I would like it to be: https://i.imgur.com/w833BdJ.png